# Memberpress custom fields - filtering content

Tags: slug

I'm working with MemberPress for a subscription site. The client requires an options within *every* plan to give the option to filter the content within their subscription based on a checkbox within their user account. This has the slug `mepr_automotive`.

1. How can I check the value of that slug from within a template?
2. If the value is `true` how can I filter the pages using `wp_list_pages` based on the fact that I'll be using a Advanced Custom Field checkbox within posts and pages to declare the post is useful for automotive users?

Thank you in advance.